# MySQL 5.6.13 count distinct result not match

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

```
    SELECT count(DISTINCT`account_id`, `company`, `department`, `title`, `start_at`, `end_at`, `type`, `create_at`, `update_at`) FROM `experience`;

    SELECT DISTINCT `account_id`, `company`, `department`, `title`, `start_at`, `end_at`, `type`, `create_at`, `update_at` FROM `experience`;
```

this two sqls' results doesn't match. first result is 3670, and second is 4564 records.

could anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

Because `COUNT DISTINCT` doesn't consider rows where exists a column value `NULL`

I try the same query with my table. In my table in some rows there are column with `NULL` value, so the result is different.

#### See [this sample SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67c2d/1)

Comment: That is the point! I found some of the columns' value is NULL, I update it with empty string, and I get the match results. Thank you!!